# Reverse border radius with css3

Tags: css

Since 3 hours I'm trying to find how to inverse border radius, I saw a small code in css3 specially for that, but I can't find it ...

You must know I'm working with wordpress (unfortunately)

Have an idea ?

Comment: Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421880/inverted-border-radius-possible

Comment: I already seen this post, and this hasn't helped me 'cause the issue use lot of <div>, but I'm on a Wordpress so put some <div> directly in the code is not a good idea .. With css3 we can do this in one line of code, but I forgotten how ^^

Comment: Well, there is no such CSS3 property as of today

Comment: So if you don't mind, I am about to vote to close this as a duplicate?

Comment: Ok, but does something more simple is existing ? Using CSS3

Comment: Just follow the dupe link and you'll find more than one way, some without adding a bunch of div's

Answer (score 17):

If your tab has a solid background color you can use pseudo elements to archive this.

---

First we create a tab with border radius in the top left and top right corners.

```
.tab {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Then we add `position: relative`, because we need to use position: absolute in the pseudo elements.

```
.tab {
    position: relative;
}
```

Now, we are going to create and position our pseudo elements as a quarter of a circle, transparent, with box-shadow to simulate borders.

```
.tab:before,
.tab:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;

    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;

    bottom: 0;
}

.tab:after {
    right: -20px;

    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #fff;
}

.tab:before {
    left: -20px;

    border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #fff;
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

**DEMO**: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nanilab/pzxk7gyr/)

```css
body {
 background: #1c1c1c;
 padding: 50px;
}

.tab {
 float: left;

 width: 90px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 height: 30px;

 position: relative;

 background: #fff;

 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.tab:before,
.tab:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;

 height: 10px;
 width: 20px;

 bottom: 0;
}

.tab:after {
 right: -20px;

 border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #fff;
 box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #fff;
}

.tab:before {
 left: -20px;

 border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #fff;
 box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab"></div>
```

Comment: In wordpress it's not very simple to add some code ^^ But I'll try something like this ! And I'll edit my first post if I find a solution :)

Comment: I can't add <div> to add a class, so I have to put a border to my elements, and when I apply a jQuery plug-in the border is ignored by the border-radius !