# Bootstrap tabs with custom corners

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tabs based on the Bootstrap 4 template, but recently I ran into this problem: I need to make smooth corners at the bottom, more details in the screenshot from the layout below.

What is available:
[image]

What should be done (I circled in red):

[image]

My code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="home1 nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#description">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="home2 nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#characteristics">Tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="home3 nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#opinion">Tab3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="description"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="characteristics"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="opinion"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse border radius with css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688253/reverse-border-radius-with-css3)

Comment: @GameO7er, no, this dont help me with my problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help.

```css
.nav-tabs .nav-link {
    position: relative;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:focus::after,
.nav-tabs .nav-link:focus::before,
.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover::after,
.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover::before,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active::after,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active::before {
    content: "";
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:focus::after,
.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover::after,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active::after {
    border-color: #fff #dee2e6 #dee2e6 #fff;
    border-radius: 0.25rem 0;
    left: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:focus::before,
.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover::before,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active::before {
    border-color: #fff #fff #dee2e6 #dee2e6;
    border-radius: 0 0.25rem;
    right: -1px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Libraries -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="home1 nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#description">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="home2 nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#characteristics">Tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="home3 nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#opinion">Tab3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="description"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="characteristics"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="opinion"></div>
</div>
```