# Inverted rounded borders css

Tags: html, css

I have huge problem in achieving effect of inverted borders like on the photo. I know how it could be looking if it would be a non transparent background, but can't figure it out when it's fully transparent. Do you have any ideas? Thank you for help.

Here is my code example for non transparent background:

```css
.box {
 width: 100px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 background-image: radial-gradient(   transparent 0px,    transparent 10px,    orangered 10px,   orangered  );
 background-size: 20px 20px;
 background-position: -10px -10px;
 &:before, &:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: orangered;
 }
 &:before {
   top: 0;
   right: 10px;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 10px;
 }
 &:after {
   top: 10px;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 0;
 }
}


.inner-round {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: orangered;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  
</div>
```

[Example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F32CC.png)

Comment: Where's your html and css?

Comment: The image isn't working for me :/

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421880/inverted-border-radius-possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invert rounded corner in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012085/invert-rounded-corner-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply this property:

```
border-radius: 100%;
```

And visit this link for more clarification:

https://codepen.io/sergejmueller/pen/fJEml