# Inverted CSS type style for "badge-like" design

Tags: html, css

I want to create a sort of badge-like box, used for team descriptions, but I can't seem to come up with any way of getting it done. I've got border-radius going for the top, but no idea how to lead up into the rest of it. This is my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/ubgbjbao/

(A little of my CSS):

```
.wpsm_team_2_member_wrapper{
        border-top-left-radius: 50%;
        border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    }
```

This is somewhat I'm trying to achieve: https://i.maagic.pw/MagnifloriousDeityMash

Comment: You're probably looking for a trick like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421880/inverted-border-radius-possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the easy route, create a png file that's just a white background with a drop shadow and/or border. 
It will be minimally slower but better than having to try to create the file with SVG which you may have to use if you want it purely html/css.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post. You'll have to get creative with your drop shadow though.

['Inverted' border-radius possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421880/inverted-border-radius-possible)

You could also try to implement this using Masking with SVG.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of mileage using absolute positioning of one element butted up to the edge of another. Here you can add a border radius (`border-radius: 50% 50% 0px 0px;`) and padding to the portrait to get that half-circle look.

The portrait you can pull upwards using a negative `top` value. The left is `left: calc(50% - 95px);` which means 50% of the containing width minus half it's own width and horizontal padding (150px/2 + 20px).

You'll have to make sure the containing element (.wpsm_team_2_member_wrapper) has `position: relative`. Add a top margin to .wpsm_team_2_member_wrapper_inner to move it down out of the way of the portrait.

Finally if you give the portrait a box shadow pointing up `box-shadow: 0px -3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.2);` you can kind of make it look like a continuous shadow.

Not sure if this is what you meant, but hopefully can get you going. Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ubgbjbao/2/